# Dashboard of Crashlytics doesn't open

Tags: android, crashlytics

I went step by step through [Fabric's tutorial](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install) and included Crashlytics in my project.  When i try to enter the Fabric dashboard, the dashboard doesn't open and I'm always redirected to the tutorial again.

[When I completed all the steps to set up Fabric and then I clicked on the dashboard, I'm redirected to this page again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkurE.png)

Comment: Try to crash in your application and then check fabric dashboard

Comment: I did that, but does not work :(

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. If your app hasn't been detected yet, try using debug mode to see if that helps: https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html

Comment: edited for clarity

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @MikeBonnell I'm facing the same issue. I've ensured that my device is connected to the internet, and have tried to force crash it multiple times. The dashboard still redirects me to onboard. (Is Google Services mandatory? Because I'm testing on an AOSP OS which does not have Play Services running)

Comment: Google Services is not required. Best to contact support(at)fabric(dot)io if you haven't already.

Comment: @MikeBonnell thanks for the prompt response. Have dropped a line to them already with Org Name, Package Name, Log, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that this line Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()); is at the onCreate of your launcher activity of your app.

For me that was the problem because it was at the onCreate of the SplashActivity when i installed Fabric.

After i repositioned this initialization line everything was working correctly and i had access to the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to run the app once before you could go to dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was occurring when I was using Safari browser.

When I changed to Chrome, everything is working like a charm

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: If stuck your firebase dashboard at “Build and run your app” check your internet connection from both side PC and Mobile and change your browser to chrome.